# AngularJS ng-if ng-show/hide within ng-repeat hiding all divs

Tags: angularjs

I have seen similar questions related to this but this is different. In most of the questions, ng-hide/show fired on ng-click event.

Here is the code.

```
$scope.showDetails = 0;

$scope.delete = function(event) {
              alert(event.target.id);
              $scope.showDetails = 1;
//There would be more code for delete function. Some Ajax calls will be here.
}
```

```
<div ng-repeat="suggestions1 in suggestions">
     <div class="col-xs-12 alert alert-info" ng-if="showDetails == '0'">
      <center> 
        <a ng-click="delete($event)" id={{suggestions1.id}} class = "btn btn-danger"> 
         <font size = "4">
            <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
         </font> 
         Delete  
        </a>
       </center>
    </div>
</div>
```

Problem is when I click on the button it hides all the divs. I am expecting one div to hide but it is hiding all the div inside ng-repeat.

I have searched for multiple questions and tried the solutions but the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's one more approach:

```
// add an array
$scope.hiddenIds = [];

<div ng-repeat="suggestions1 in news_suggestions">
     <!-- check if hidden -->
     <div ng-hide=" hiddenIds.indexOf(suggestions1.id)>-1 " class="col-xs-12 alert alert-info">
      <center> 
        <!-- remove/add to hidden array on click -->
        <a ng-click=" hiddenIds.indexOf(suggestions1.id)>-1 ? hiddenIds.splice(hiddenIds.indexOf(suggestions1.id),1) : hiddenIds.push(suggestions1.id) " id={{suggestions1.id}} class = "btn btn-danger">
```

Here you don't modify the existing collection of elements.

*Hint*: if you hide the show/hide button, you won't be able to show the element back again. So you probably want to change your html layout a bit ;)

**EDIT**

Version 2:
You can always move it from your html to the scope.

```
// add an array
$scope.hiddenIds = [];

$scope.checkHide = function(suggestions1){
    return $scope.hiddenIds.indexOf(suggestions1.id)>-1;
};

$scope.clickHide = function(suggestions1){
    $scope.hiddenIds.indexOf(suggestions1.id)>-1 ? $scope.hiddenIds.splice($scope.hiddenIds.indexOf(suggestions1.id),1) : $scope.hiddenIds.push(suggestions1.id) ;
};



<div ng-repeat="suggestions1 in news_suggestions">
     <!-- check if hidden -->
     <div ng-hide="checkHide(suggestions1)" class="col-xs-12 alert alert-info">
      <center> 
        <!-- remove/add to hidden array on click -->
        <a ng-click="clickHide(suggestions1)" id={{suggestions1.id}} class = "btn btn-danger">
```

**EDIT 2**

If you don't need that element in news_suggestions (you're not planning to show it back again), you can simply remove it, which is even easier :)

```
$scope.remove = function(i){
    $scope.news_suggestions.splice(i,1);
};

<div ng-repeat="suggestions1 in news_suggestions track by $index">
     <div class="col-xs-12 alert alert-info">
      <center> 
        <!-- remove by index on click  -->
        <a ng-click="remove($index)" id={{suggestions1.id}} class = "btn btn-danger">
```

[**JSBin**](https://jsbin.com/luguco/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: I don't want to show it again. Once it deleted it will be gone. Let me try your solution.

Comment: @Ironic, so there's no problem with this button then :)

Comment: Unfortunately, i can't change ng-click with your code because i have to execute ajax call for delete function.

Comment: @Ironic, yes, if you need more complex code, you better off moving this code into the controller, please, check my edit.

Comment: I tried Edit 2 and it is removing first div no matter if i select another.

Comment: @Ironic, there must be something else wrong, and I can only guess what :) I added a JSBin. Maybe `track by $index` ? Or you got multiple ng-repeats ....

Comment: This does the trick. news_suggestions track by $index without it not working. Update the answer. So, other can use it. I will accept it after that.

Comment: @Ironic, I just did, glad it helped :)

Answer (score 3):

In that case you need to have a property named showDetails in each object of your new_suggestions array and enable ng-if based on that.

```
<div ng-repeat="suggestions1 in news_suggestions">
     <div class="col-xs-12 alert alert-info" ng-if="suggestions1.showDetails == '0'">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me try. Voted Up. Only One question suggestions1.showDetails I don't have any variable in suggestions1. How it will work?

Comment: Should I put 1 or 0 in suggestions1.showDetails? I am making changes in Ajax code so, it will return showdetails value.

Comment: You can have Boolean value either true/false it should be in each object

Comment: I don't think it will work because it will be for all the divs. so, either all will be hidden or visible. I want to hide one div not entire div those are generated by ng-repeat.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is logically wrong. You are keeping only one copy of showDetails variable. You need some property which is related to each object.

Try like this

```
$scope.delete = function(index) {
              $scope.news_suggestions[index].hideDetails = true;
}


<div ng-repeat="suggestions1 in news_suggestions">
     <div class="col-xs-12 alert alert-info" ng-hide="suggestions1.hideDetails">
      <center> <a ng-click="delete($index)" id={{suggestions1.id}} class = "btn btn-danger"> <font size = "4"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></font> Delete  </a> </center></div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me try. Voted Up.

Comment: No but divs are not getting hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, something wrong with your logic. Try this:

```
$scope.delete = function(el){
     el.hideDetails = true;
}


<div ng-repeat="suggestions1 in news_suggestions">
 <div class="col-xs-12 alert alert-info" ng-hide="hideDetails">
  <center> <a ng-click="delete(this)" id={{suggestions1.id}} class = "btn btn-danger"> <font size = "4"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></font> Delete  </a> </center></div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me try. Voted up.